# Haproxy http not redirect to https

Tags: haproxy

haproxy.cfg like below

```
frontend haproxy_front
  mode http

  bind *:3333 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/my.pem
  http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

  http-response del-header Server
  default_backend myapp

backend myapp
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  server myapp_1 <ip>:3000
```

When I access as 'http://<haproxy.host>:3333', redirect is not working. What should i do?
But 'https://<haproxt.host>:3333' work well.

Comment: You should also provide the location you want your redirect to go to. Please see [Docs here](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#redirect) Focus on the `redirect scheme` in docs

Comment: @SebastianGbudje I read a Docs But,, Doc propose only 'redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }'. You means that i should add 'redirect localhost: too?

Comment: You already use SSL on 3333 (`bind *:3333 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/my.pem`), so plain HTTP connection to 3333 won't work. You can't have HTTP and HTTPS on the same port AFAIR.

Comment: @DaeYoung if that’s where you want to redirect the traffic to then yes. The docs specifies how to setup the redirect path as well. You need to tell it where you want it to redirect to. It won’t just resolve there. If you don’t provide a redirect location, it’ll just stay on the same page and not redirect